# change top styling of each child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an div which have children which will variate by the users choose. I am looping over these elements and change the top position with jquery like this:

```
var top = 0;

$('.shareBtn').each(function(index, item) {
  top += 66;    
  console.log(top, item, index);

  $(item).eq(index).css("top", top + "px");
})
```

However this only appending `top: 66px` to the first element. How can I append top styling `+66px` for every item?

Out of the comments I see that my query isn't clear enough. I want to added 66px every item the each loop counts.

So if the loop index is 0,1,2 I want to see a top styling like this:

```
<div class="shareBtn" style="top: 0;"></div>
<div class="shareBtn" style="top: 66px;"></div>
<div class="shareBtn" style="top: 132px;"></div>
```

Comment: That should work for all elements, although note that it's waaaay over-complicated. You can just use: `$('.shareBtn').css('top', '66px');`. If that still doesn't work for you then please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question

Comment: It could really help if you made a codepen/jsfiddle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no I think you don't get my query, I want to add + 66px every item there is

Comment: You mean you want to add `66` to their current value?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that more looks like a vertical stack of items where top lines of each are 66px between.

Comment: Why are you using eq? Item should equal all of the child elements of ".shareBtn"

Comment: @lolbas I'm not sure what you're referring to?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan bad wording maybe, Gavin Thomas's answer is what I meant.

Comment: @Sireini just remove `.eq(index)` and it should works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already calling `.each()` - when you then index it, you're targeting one in particular.

```
var top = 0;

$('.shareBtn').each(function(index, item){
  top += 66;

  console.log(top, item, index);

  $(this).css("top", top + "px");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47fdz9mc/

Comment: and how do I make the position of the first element 0?

Comment: ... move `top += 66` down to after your `.css` statement?